# empty class field in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On the Rails Guide, I saw a class was defined as

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and then it wrote

```
>>p = Person.new(:name => "John Doe")
=>#<Person id: nil, name: "John Doe", created_at: nil, :updated_at: nil
```

Since class Person has no field, why here it is valid to pass a :name attribute to the constructor? Shouldn't there be some error with it?

Also, why id, name, created_at all have no colon but :updated_at has one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your class inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` and ActiveRecords looks at your database and dynamically creates attributes that match the columns in the corresponding database table.

`updated_at` doesn't have a column either. Please look again carefully. It must be a mistake.

Comment: Why we do not need attributes_accessible here?

Comment: It does have on the online guide, but maybe it's a typo.

Comment: Yeah, that must be a typo. So the code here is not actually *your* code? You copied it from Rails Guides?

Comment: Yes. I'm reading Rails Guide and could not understand this part.

Comment: In Rails 3.2, you *do* need `attr_accessible`. I don't know why they omitted that in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

To see the fields defined in an ActiveRecord class you need to look at the `db/schema.rb` file.  That will show you the fields that have been created through migrations.